# Deploying a Rails App to VPS, with NginX Server. Compile Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compilation

I successfully deployed my rails app to my VPS, but when I try to look at my server from browser, I get a 500 error ("We're sorry, but something's wrong"). The app is working fine locally, so I think the problem lies in not my code but somewhere else.

Here's the log from /current/log/production.log

```
ActionView::Template::Error (jquery.js isn't precompiled):
    4:   <title>Songhomme</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>
8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
9: </head>
10: <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2525571063257357898_28769560'
```

I also got the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (/home/deployer/apps/songhomme/releases/20121204091428/app/views/posts/_posts.erb:27: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...ppend= ( link_to (t.name + " ", '/tags/' + t.id.to_s) );@out...
```

The code is working fine locally, so I'm not sure what's wrong with the second part of code. For the first part of code, does running `rake assets:precompile` before I push to my repo solve the problem?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring your js includes in the manifest file application.js , not by javascript_include_tag. Since Rails version 3 this is the proper way . So , in your application.js :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```